# Force data-ajax="false" on a redirect, or on a certain page load

Tags: jquery-mobile

Let's say that I have a link to a page such as:

```
<a class="ui-btn" data-transition="slide" href="/Stuff/Properties/Q6158">Properties for Q6158"</a>
```

Normally, I would want this page to slide into view and thus data-ajax would be default "true" and this works fine.  But what if on the server side, something happens that causes me to instead want to redirect to a different page, and not to load it using ajax?  In other words, the user's session has expired and I'd like to reload the entire login page, not just slide it into view instead of the requested page.  Hope that makes sense.

I realize that by the time the request gets to the server and it figures out the session has disappeared, it's kind of too late to change the request, it's already been made by jQM.  I suppose I could handle the click of the link myself and handle a custom "redirect" response manually, but that seems overly cumbersome because basically every link on the site is affected by this.

So I'm out of ideas.  I'd really like the entire login page to be fully reloaded at this point.  Any ideas would be helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: What version of JQM are you using? And are you using multi-page or single page model?

Comment: 1.4.3 multi-page(?).  i.e., each page is loaded via AJAX.

Comment: That means single page model, each page in a separate file. You can check if session has expired before page changes `pagecontainerbeforechange` and then you can redirect user to login page with or without ajax.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you can control the session and in the ajax call, if the session has expired, return an 404 error.

In jQuery Mobile there is an event called "pageloadfailed" that's triggered when a page load fails. There you cold redirect to your login page.

```
$( document ).on( "pageloadfailed", function( event, data ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //redirect to your login page
});
```

Hope that works.

Comment: While I think this is a good suggestion and gives me something to think about, I do not believe I want to do this for every 404 in my case.

Comment: @JamesR. you could return a HTTP 3xx code [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection] from your server ajax call, so if the session has expired, redirect the user to the login page. Don't really know how will jQM handle this, but it should redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up introducing a third page.  I return this page I call "Loading" when the session has expired.  All the page does is display "Loading, please wait..." and instantly sets location.url to the login page in the pageinit causing login to be fully reloaded.  Seems to work well so far for my particular situation.  But thanks for the other suggestions!